# F# and MEF: Exporting Functions

Tags: f#, mef

So, I was trying to get this simple test working in an F# console app:

```
open System.Reflection
open System.ComponentModel.Composition
open System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting

[<Export(typeof<int -> string>)>]
let toString(i: int) = i.ToString()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    use catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
    use container = new CompositionContainer(catalog)

    let myFunction = container.GetExportedValue<int -> string>()
    let result = myFunction(5)
    0
```

I expected MEF to get the function properly resolved, but it doesn't.
Instead, I get this:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   `'System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionContractMismatchException'`
>   occurred in System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
>
> Additional information:
>
> ``` Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type 'Program.toString (ContractName="Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc(System.Int32,System.String)")'  to type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc``2[System.Int32,System.String]'. ```

- What am I missing here?
- What is the difference between `FSharpFunc(System.Int32, System.String)` and ``` FSharpFunc``2[System.Int32, System.String] ```?
- What is the correct way to import/export F# functions via MEF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler turns top-level F# functions into methods, so your example will be compiled as:

```
[Export(FSharpFunc<int,string>)]
public string toString(int i) { return i.ToString(); }
```

This is probably causing the error. You can force the compiler to produce a property getter of `FSharpFunc` type by calling some operation that returns a function - even a simple identity function will don:

```
let makeFunc f = f 

[<Export(typeof<int -> string>)>]
let toString = makeFunc <| fun (i:int) -> 
  i.ToString()
```

I have not tested this, but I think it could work. That said, it is probably safer to go with a simple single-method interface in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm precisely trying to get rid of interfaces. I figured most of my code only needs the actual functions, not the containing types, or any interface stuff.

Comment: Also: you mentioned this is only for top-level functions, right? what if I put all my `[<Export>]`ed functions as nested functions?

Comment: ...Argh.. Right. I can't apply attributes to nested functions. Is there any MEF-like library that will play nicer with F#, while still be able to be consumed by C# code?

Comment: Alternatively, I think you should be able to use a signature file (and signature `(int -> string)` instead of `int -> string`) to achieve the same result.

Comment: @kvb can you elaborate on that?

Comment: For the record, using `Func<T>` and `Action<T>` works just fine, though it's not as elegant as using native F# function syntax

Comment: @HighCore see section 11.2.1.1 of the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf).